# The construction of moduli space of stable maps

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces

In [FP-notes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9608011.pdf) for proving existence of $\overline{M}_{0,n}(P^r,d)$ we first defined $\bar{t}$-rigid stable family and found fine modulo space for it where $\bar{t}=(t_0,...,t_r)$ is basis for $H^0(P^r,O(1)).$ and $(U\rightarrow \overline{M}(\bar{t}),{p_i},q_i,_j,\mu)$ is universal family.

for other basis $\bar{t^\prime}$ they consider open subset $\overline{M}(\bar{t},\bar{t^\prime})$ $\subset$ $\overline{M}(\bar{t})$ the locus which $\mu^*(\bar{t_i^\prime})$ are etale disjoint and disjoint from ${p_i}$.  now to construct $\overline{M}_{0,n}(P^r,d)$ in proposition 4 in page 19 they imply that for other basis $\bar{t^\prime}$, $\mu^*(\bar{t_i^\prime})$ define an etale galois cover $E$ with galois group $G$ over which $\bar{t^\prime}$ rigid family is defined.

I cant understand how we have this covering.